# Apache redirect domain without www to the same with www except one page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm new in apache redirect.
I want to redirect example.org (without www) to www.example.org except one page
so I did this :

```
<VirtualHost *:8001>
    ServerName example.org
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.org$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

and it doesn't work

Have any idea ? 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your `.htaccess` instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(example)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

The first condition checks to see if `www` is not present. The second condition makes sure that it is not the directory `example`. If both of these conditions are met, then it will force `www`.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I still have the www in result : http://www.example.org/robots.txt

Comment: See my edit and try that. Don't forget to clear your cache before testing.